# Makefile with commands depending on each other

Tags: bash, makefile

I'm a newbie with makefiles and i'm trying to write one that executes several commands. Each command outputs different files which are then passed to the next one.

```
SOURCE=sequencer
ENCODINGS= j a m o r
FILES= $(foreach enc,$(ENCODINGS),$(SOURCE)$(enc))

all: syf boom boog loon proof scapin 
syf : $(SOURCE).fsm
    for enc in j a m o u r ; do syf -CEV -$$enc $(SOURCE); done
boom : $(foreach file,$(FILES),$(file)_b.vbe)
boog : $(foreach file,$(FILES),$(file)_b.vst)
loon : $(foreach file,$(FILES),$(file)_b_l.vst)
proof : $(foreach file,$(FILES),$(file)_b_l_net.vbe)
scapin : $(foreach file,$(FILES),$(file)_b_l_scan.vst)


#------------------Behavioral Optimization---------------------#

%_b.vbe: %.vbe  
    @echo "    Boolean Optimization -> $@  "
    boom -d 50 $* $*_b

#------------------Standard Cell Mapping-----------------------#

%.vst : %.vbe
    @echo "    Logical Synthesis -> $@  "
    boog -x 0 -l paramfile $*

#------------------Netlist Optimization------------------------#

%_l.vst : %.vst paramfile.lax
    @echo "    Netlist Optimization -> $@ "
    loon -x 0 -l paramfile $* $*_l 

#------------------Netlist compare-----------------------------#

%_b_l_net.vbe : %_b_l.vst %.vbe
    @echo "    Formal checking -> $@ "
    flatbeh $*_b_l $*_b_l_net
    proof -d $* $*_b_l_net

#------------------Scan-path insertion-------------------------#

%_scan.vst : %.vst scan.path
    @echo "    scan-path insertion -> $@ "
    scapin -VRB $* scan $*_scan

clear :
    @echo "Erase all the files generated by the makefile" 
    rm -f *.vbe *.enc *.vst *.xsc
```

The previous code outputs the following error when I run `make all` for the first time.

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'sequencerj_b.vbe', needed by 'boom'.  Stop.
```

The first command `syf` is executed successfully and outputs the proper files. But, the command `boom` fails to run. However, when i run `make all` for a second time -without deleting the files- the makefile finishes its operation successfully. Am i missing something? Maybe `boom` doesn't wait for `syf` to finish running.

### What the commands do :

foo.fsm -> `syf` -> fooj.vbe -> `boom`
 -> fooj_b.vbe -> `boog` -> fooj_b.vst -> `loon` -> fooj_b_l.vst

fooj_b_l.vst -> `flatbeh` -> fooj_b_l_net.vbe

fooj_b_l.vst -> `scapin` -> fooj_b_l_scan.vst

`proof` just compares 2 files with no outputs

Comment: It looks for me that cyclic dependence is here: `boom` depends on `sequencerj_b.vbe` which implicitly depends on `boom` itself according to "Behavioral Optimization" rule. By term "implicitly" I mean that you didn't added this last dependency to Makefile dependency list but still it is used in rule command.

Comment: @gudok I'm not really following. How does  `sequencerj_b.vbe implicitly depends on boom`. Well first off syf outputs the file `sequencerj.vbe` and then the rule `boom` is called which depends on `sequencerj_b.vbe` which depends on the rule `Behavioral Optimization` which depends on `sequencerj.vbe`. Am i right? Where is the cyclic part?

Comment: If you want boom to wait syf to finish running, you should simply put syf as a prerequisite of boom.

Comment: @AdrienHorgnies Changed the boom line to `boom : syf $(foreach file,$(FILES),$(file)_b.vbe)` , but the issue still holds.

Comment: Could you tell us what each of these commands (`syf`, `boom`, ...) reads and writes? For example, `syf` reads `foo` and writes `foo.vbe`, then `boom` reads `foo.vbe` and writes `foo_b.vbe`, an so on.

Comment: @Beta edited the post for a more clear explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two paragraphs of Beta's answer are spot-on, only the proposed solution does not work.

To remedy the problem, replace the `syf` target name with the real target file names, and change the command line accordingly so that `make` gets the information about the file actually generated - i. e. replace

```
all: syf boom boog loon proof scapin 
syf : $(SOURCE).fsm
    for enc in j a m o u r ; do syf -CEV -$$enc $(SOURCE); done
```

with

```
# These are the files to be made by the command "syf ...":
syf=$(FILES:=.vbe) $(SOURCE)u.vbe

all: $(syf) boom boog loon proof scapin 
$(syf) : $(SOURCE).fsm
    syf -CEV -$(patsubst $(SOURCE)%.vbe,%,$@) $(SOURCE)
```

- now all the individual target files (`sequencerj.vbe sequencera.vbe sequencerm.vbe sequencero.vbe sequencerr.vbe sequenceru.vbe`) are specified in the rule, and the `syf` command line has to create just one of the files; the needed encoding option is extracted from the target name by the [`patsubst` function for string substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html), e. g. `$(patsubst sequencer%.vbe,%,sequencerj.vbe)` produces `j`.

Comment: I didn't quite get Beta's answer. `boom` requires `sequencerj_b.vbe` which requires `sequencerj.vbe` which should have been already produced by the `syf` rule before the `boom` rule is called. Am I missing smth?

Comment: You are right, _`sequencerj.vbe`_ indeed does _have been already produced by the `syf` rule before the boom rule is called._ But the problem is that `make` tests the presence of `sequencerj.vbe` at the beginning (before the `syf` rule is called) and doesn't retest thereafter, because, like Beta wrote, _Make doesn't know how to build_ `sequencerj.vbe`; _the `syf` rule builds it, but Make doesn't know that._ So Make has no reason to "think" the file could have been produced, and continues to "think" it doesn't exist. When running Make for a second time, `sequencerj.vbe` exists and all goes well.

Comment: Thank you @Armali, I'm wondering as to how you reached this post after almost a year and a half.

Comment: @usfmohy - Presently I'm going over some older questions with no upvoted and no accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

The visible error is caused by the fact that Make doesn't know what these rules produce. It knows that `boom` requires `sequencerj_b.vbe`, but it doesn't know how to build that file; the `syf` rule builds it, but Make doesn't know that.

This is exactly the kind of problem that Make is designed to solve, but the rules must be written to provide the needed information.

You have a complex build system which I can't reproduce, so this may take a few iterations. Start by removing everything above "Behaviour Optimization" and replacing it with this::

```
SOURCE=sequencer

TARGETS := $(patsubst %, $(SOURCE)%_b_l.vst, j a m o r)

all: $(TARGETS)

$(SOURCE)%.vbe: $(SOURCE)%.fsm
    syf -CEV -$* $(SOURCE)
```

Give that a try, and tell us how it goes (in a comment to this answer).

Comment: This produces another complication. Both the rules `$(SOURCE)%.vbe: $(SOURCE).fsm` and `%_b.vbe: %.vbe` are called when `sequencerj_b.vbe` since they produces the same file but make favors the first one since the `sequencer.fsm` is ready. However, the second one must be chosen since `sequencerj_b.vbe` is the output of boog.

Comment: @usfmohy: The first rule is `$(SOURCE)%.vbe: $(SOURCE)%.fsm`, which *cannot* be used to build `sequencerj_b.vbe` unless `sequencerj_b.fsm` exists, which I presume it does not. And according to your summary, the output of `boog` is `sequencerj_b.vst`. Have I misunderstood you?

Comment: Edited the post. The input file to syf `foo.fsm` outputs files with their encoding `fooj.vbe`, `fooa.vbe`, .. etc.. It's a single file used several times with the same tool syf. Sorry if I caused you any misunderstanding.